# Take affect of changing local environments into vscode debugger

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, vscode-debugger

I have an issue in Linux `ubuntu 18.0.4` or any other distributions,when I change my local environments from `~/.bashrc` file, it doesn't change in debug mode of vscode.

it changes only when I close vscode internal terminal and again start it, and run the program from vscode terminal.(Every thing ok in this situation)

But at that time when I use debug mode of vscode, my local envs don't change at all! I have to just restart my PC to local envs take effect normally!!

what should I do to tell debugger of vscode to restart itself?

Comment: check `launch.json` in the current directory

Comment: @RaminNietzsche I don't want to read from `launch.json` . I want to read from my system env.